# How to make tree structure with tuples in Erlang

Tags: tree, erlang, red-black-tree

I'm clearly new to Erlang. I want to make a red-black tree with tuples, which has {Key, Value, Color, Left, Right}. When i add the first item to my tree it looks like this: {2,"something", b, nil, nil}, because it doesn't have any childs yet. My problem is that, if i want to add the next item, as a left or right child of this  tree, i can't add it.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have:

```
T = {2, "something", b, nil, nil}.
```

To insert something in the left branch, we can do something like:

```
insert_left(X, {Key, Value, Color, Left, Right}) ->
    {Key, Value, Color, insert_left(X, Left), Right};
insert_left(X, nil) -> X.
```

Or perhaps a bit more unreadable:

```
insert_left(X, {K, V, C, L, R} = T) ->
   V = insert_left(X, L),
   setelement(4, T, V).
```

Now we can insert something:

```
insert_left(5, T).
```

A proper RB-implementation will implement `insert` by considering the subtree based on the key. It will also wrap the remaining tree in a `balance` function to maintain the RB-invariant. Expect there to be around 12 lines of code all in all (plus/minus 10).

Answer (score 0):

Well you can actually take a look at stdlib's `gb_trees` module ([to the documentation](http://erldocs.com/17.0-rc1/stdlib/gb_trees.html?i=0&search=gb_trees#undefined))
as most Erlang/OTP data structures are just a combination of tuples, atoms, lists and numbers.